# Passing decimal to stored procedure with differing culture

Tags: c#, sql-server, decimal

I was trying to pass a decimal(Google latitude and longitude) to a stored procedure with c#. I put a Replace whether the received data was delimited with point instead of coma.

Already tried CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and other methods which determines the delimiter.

The method worked perfectly on my computer but when i tried to run on the server it crashed.

On my pc the delimiter is `'.'` instead of `','` which is set on the server.

Example for data: `49,088581`

This error message shows up when the query was executed:

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

Read the following code:

```
SqlParameter latPar = new SqlParameter();
latPar.Precision = 18;
latPar.Scale = 6;
latPar.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
latPar.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(lat.Replace('.', ',') == "" ? "0,00" : lat.Replace('.', ','));
latPar.ParameterName = "@lat";
command.Parameters.Add(latPar);



SqlParameter longPar = new SqlParameter();
longPar.Precision = 18;
longPar.Scale = 6;
longPar.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
longPar.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(lon.Replace('.', ',') == "" ? "0,00" : lon.Replace('.', ','));
longPar.ParameterName = "@long";
command.Parameters.Add(longPar);
```

Comment: What is the code  when you used the CultureInfo parameter?

Comment: "Example for data: 49,088581" - what's giving you the data with a comma in? How are you obtaining `lat` and `long` to start with?

Comment: Have you looked at the `SqlParameter.LocaleId` property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.localeid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: decimal decLat = Convert.ToDecimal(lat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    decimal decLon = Convert.ToDecimal(lon, 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Also tried with SqlParameter.LocaleId

Comment: `private void store_Signal(string jelsor)
{
   string[] jelsorParam = jelsor.Split(';');
   string lat = jelsorParam[2];
   string lon = jelsorParam[3];
}`
@Eris

Comment: The separator for the invariant culture is always `.`, no matter the server setting. `Decimal.Parse(lat.Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` should work -- if it does not, verify that `lat` really contains what you expect. Note that the format used by SQL Server should be irrelevant in this case, because the parameter is itself a `decimal`, not a `string`, so no string conversion occurs.

Comment: It's working now... the problem was not in this conversion.. 
But thanks for all the help! :)